# Bootstrap 3.2 and IE9 collapse function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Im using bootstrap 3.2 and Jquery 1.11.1. The webapp works fine in all major browser including IE 10 and 11. Im using the .collapse('toggle') function for the navbar. In other browsers it adds the "in" class but for some reason that does not happen the first time I open the menu in IE 9. Subsequent calls add the ".in" class and remove it. The first click does not trigger it.

How to make it work properly in IE9?

Comment: Please post the full code of your webpage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got your CSS from CDN (bootstrapcdn.com) respond.js only works for local files. So try your website on IE9 with a local copy of bootstrap.css. Or read: CDN/X-Domain Setup

Update:

Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

> In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of respond.js to
>   enable media query support.

See also: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

For this reason, the basic template contains these lines in the `<head>` section:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Im not using a CDN so far (using bower so local libraries) and the template contains that piece that you mention.

Comment: @kitimenpolku Just download these files and put it before the `<html>` tag.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this in the future. This is not an answer to the question as it clearly shows how to use html5shiv and respond on IE 8 and the question is specifically for IE 9.